# ID sequence when cell value change

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet with values like

```
A
A
B
C
C
C
D
E
```

I would like to an ID next the them, but the sequence should only increment when the original value changes, so I would get something like

```
A - 1
A - 1
B - 2
C - 3
C - 3
C - 3
D - 4
E - 5
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your data is in *Column A* then on cell `B1` put an *1* as starting ID.

For cell `B2` should be:

```
=IF(A2=A1,B1,B1+1)
```

Copy the formula to B2,B3,B4,etc.